# How big is the EOS blockchain? Does it grow much faster compared to others due to the short blocktimes?

Tags: blockchains, block-size

How big is the EOS blockchain in disk size? Since its faster block times, doesn't the size of the blockchain grow much faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download a snapshot of the blockchain form [here](https://eosnode.tools/blocks), untar it and check the size.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2018 October EOS size is 29GB after coming on live since May 2018. It's about 6GB a month or 72GB a year or average 100GB a year assuming its actively used.